# long table in latex won't make neat columns

Tags: longtable

I have a long table I need split over multiple tables. I know that I don't use the \begin{tabular} in the \begin{longtable} environment, but I can't figure out how to get the columns in the long table to align.

Here's my table

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{longtable}\footnotesize 
{|p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}|}       
\hline       
\textbf{Positive Diplomacy Actions} & \textbf{Negative Diplomacy Actions} \\ 
\hline       
\endfirsthead       
\hline      \\
\hline       
\endhead 

Accede to demands for change in institutions, regime    & Accuse \\
Accede to demands for change in leadership &    Accuse of aggression \\
Accede to demands for change in policy  &Accuse of crime, corruption \\
Accede to demands for rights    &Accuse of espionage, treason\\
Acknowledge or claim responsibility & Accuse of human rights abuses\\
Allow humanitarian access   & Accuse of war crimes\\
Apologize   & Appeal for change in institutions, regime \\
Appeal for aid  & Appeal for change in leadership \\
Appeal for diplomatic cooperation (such as policy support)& Appeal for de-escalation of military engagement\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]
Any help on how to get second column to line up like when you use the tabular environment? Thanks!

Comment: even if I add the missing `\usepackage` and `begin{document}` I get  `! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.` from `\begin{longtable} \footnotesize `  Please post a real example that shows your problem.

Comment: If I move the `\footnotesize`  [i get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8jXb.png) which is as I expect?

Comment: This was copied and pasted directly from document that compiles for me. Removing \footnotesize doesn't change anything....I added a picture of the output I get

Comment: I don't get that output.  I get something close to it if I move `\footnotesize` back to where you erroneously had it.

Comment: Showed result is not produced by code which you provide in question. Se first part of my answer.

Comment: Are you ignoring errors in your compilation?  Because the output looks nothing like your code, but does suggest TeX trying to make a best guess at what you meant.  If you have errors in your compilation, then your question has to be "how can I fix this error", not "why is the output incorrect".

Comment: you could only get the output you show if you have an error. After any error you should ignore the pdf output and ask about the error message, but I will revert that part of my edit and restore the error in your example

Answer (score 1):

- Considering @DavidCarlisle comment and move `footnotesize` before `longtable` or just remove them, your code can be compiled and gives the following result:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

- So, it is not clear what is your problem. That table is wider than `\textwidth` because you specify column widths as `p{0.5\textwidth}`?
- In this case you need to change column specification to:

```
\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|}}
```

and will get a table, which not protrude out of text block:

[image]

- Simpler code and a wee bit nicer (according to my opinion) result you can get by use of the `tabularray˙ package instead of` longtable`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Long table},
  label = {tab:long}
                ]{vlines,
                  colspec = {X[l] X[l]},
                  cells= {font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                  row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
    \toprule
Positive Diplomacy Actions & Negative Diplomacy Actions    \\
    \midrule
%%%%
Accede to demands for change in institutions, regime    & Accuse \\
Accede to demands for change in leadership &    Accuse of aggression \\
Accede to demands for change in policy  &Accuse of crime, corruption \\
Accede to demands for rights    &Accuse of espionage, treason\\
Acknowledge or claim responsibility & Accuse of human rights abuses\\
Allow humanitarian access   & Accuse of war crimes\\
Apologize   & Appeal for change in institutions, regime \\
Appeal for aid  & Appeal for change in leadership \\
Appeal for diplomatic cooperation (such as policy support)& Appeal for de-escalation of military engagement\\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Tabularray worked perfectly.

Comment: @KEA, also your original code works fine, if you consider my suggestion how to specify table's columns. Let me repeat, showed result in edited question is not produced by provided document example. So please clarify your question.